# Invisible Markers in game map - Unity 2D Game

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

How can I place specific points on my 2D tile map that are invisible and do not obstruct any movement in the game, and when the player interacts with this it fires some code. Any help would be great, thanks!

Let me know if more description needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a BoxCollider2D as a trigger (i.e. set the IsTrigger flag to true).  You can override the OnTriggerEnter2d method to fire off your code when something enters the bounds of the collider.

Setting the IsTrigger flag will cause the collider to NOT block any actors. It will simply trigger the events as the collider is entered / touched / exited etc.

See the API [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BoxCollider2D.html)

Comment: You should reference the BoxCollider2D and OnTriggerEnter2D calls if they're looking for 2D functionality. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html

Comment: wouldnt the boxcollider obstruct the path of the player though?

Comment: @dmkanerer Not if you set the `isTrigger` property on the boxcollider component to true.

Comment: if i have a bunch of box colliders already though how can i make this specific one fire different code

Comment: attach `box colllider 2D` to a specific `gameObject` and acces that collider (with trigger set to true ) through that gameObject .In this way that specific  one(gameObject) will fire specific code